# Evenly space TextViews across screen with right and left justification

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to space out 3 TextViews across the width of the screen, with the 1st TextView touching the left margin, and the 3rd TextView touching the right margin.

Currently I'm able to achieve the following:

|text[space]text[space]text[space]|

and

|[space]text[space]text[space]text|

and

|[space/2]text[space]text[space]text[space/2]|

By setting left, right, and center gravities, respectively, within a horizontal ListView.

I want to achieve:

|text[space]text[space]text|

But I can't seem to get it. Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graph_xaxis_labels"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linegraph_fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_0"
    android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/12"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/13"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/14"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS: I know hardcoding TextView text is bad. That's only temporary.

Comment: btw: 8sp is too small for a text view and can be really hard to read on big screens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. You're missing the Gravity.

**UPDATE**: To center more than three, you need to change the layout… updated below for 6 labels: (The hint was given by Haresh answer) It has a few drawbacks but should do the trick.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/graph_xaxis_labels"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_0"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/12"/>
  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/13"/>
  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/14"/>
  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/15"/>
  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/16"/>
  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="8sp"
      android:text="02/17"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if I wanted to achieve even spacing with right/left justification with more than 3 TextViews? Say 7

Comment: Well that is a little bit harder because you're forcing the left/right most to be left/right respectively aligned. But the spacing would be the same (for each view) if you add more TextViews between those two with `0dp width`, `weight 1` and `center_horizontal` gravity.

Comment: Real "justification" would require you to measure the container, then each view independently and do some math to position them in the screen. It's a lot more trickier.

Comment: Thinking about it, the math would be (something along these lines): You need: sum of each textview width (no space). Total available space (the width of the container), available space left to distribute (total - sumWidth). With that Available space, divide it by the number of textviews and calculate where they go. It's messy but doable. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/graph_xaxis_labels"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linegraph_fragment"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/12"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/13"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:text="02/14"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing gravity for 2 nd 3rd textview ..try this way

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_0"
android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:text="02/12"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:text="02/13"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_xaxis_2"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:text="02/14"
    />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but if you want to add items programatically and dynamically, here is the sample code 
[github](https://github.com/SwordArtist/DynamicEvenSpreadingView)